# Send message from an Azure ServiceBus Topic after a specific delay with node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Basically, within an Azure Service Bus, I have a topic and a subscription.

If a message arrives in the topic between 11:00AM, my subscriber should not handle it yet. 
However, at 14:00PM, I would expect my subscriber to treat it.

Is there a way to achieve this natively with Topic filters?

I don't find any mention of this kind of use case in the official documentation regarding filters.
Indeed, all presented samples are about:
"**subscriber handling this kind of message, or never**".
I'm looking for:
"**subscriber expecting handling this kind of message but, but later at a specific time**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to defer a message ?

Don't know much about the [Azure SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node) but from the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc.aspx) you can set a `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` on the message :

> The scheduled enqueue time in UTC. This value is for delayed message sending. It is utilized to delay messages sending to a specific time in the future.

Only sample to [send a message to a Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/#send-messages-to-a-queue) is :

```
var message = {
    body: 'Test message',
    customProperties: {
        testproperty: 'TestValue'
}};
serviceBusService.sendQueueMessage('myqueue', message, function(error){
    if(!error){
        // message sent
    }
});
```

From the nodejs sdk, I found a [constants.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/common/lib/util/constants.js) file that defines these properties  :

```
/**
* The broker properties for service bus queue messages.
*
* @const
* @type {string}
*/
BROKER_PROPERTIES_HEADER: 'brokerproperties',
...
/**
* The scheduled enqueue time header.
*
* @const
* @type {string}
*/
SCHEDULED_ENQUEUE_TIME_HEADER: 'x-ms-scheduled-enqueue-time',
```

If you have a look at the [servicebusservice.js](http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs/servicebusservice.js.html), there is a `setRequestHeaders` function that takes some properties of the message and set it as header.

So I guess you can set this property on the message like that :

```
// Set your scheduled date
var scheduledDate = Date.now();
scheduledDate.setHours(scheduledDate.getHours()+3);

var message = {
    body: 'Test message',
    brokerproperties: {
        'x-ms-scheduled-enqueue-time': scheduledDate.toUTCString()
}};
```

Let me know if it works :-)

Comment: I will test it this week and I'll let you know there :) Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work, my team will make some other tests to valid that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using this:

```
        const scheduledDate = new Date();
        scheduledDate.setMinutes(scheduledDate.getMinutes()+1);

        const message = {
        body: 'Hey, this worked again!',
        customProperties: {
            testproperty: 'TestValue'
        },
        brokerProperties: {
            ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc: scheduledDate.toUTCString()
        }
    };
    serviceBusService.sendQueueMessage('myqueue', message, function(error){
        if(!error){
            console.log('We sent a message. Huzzah!');
        }
    });
```