# Service Bus Queue output binding for Azure Functions doesn't support 'ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc'?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to write an azure function that supports 'retries' or future calls based on a service bus queue. It seems that the output bindings don't support any `brokerProperties` in the payload, is this correct or am I simply doing it wrong?

I'm able to do future calls in the queue with the following:

```
const azure = require('azure-sb');
const moment = require('moment');

const scheduled_time = moment().utc().add(5, 'm').format('M/D/YYYY H:mm:ss A');
const msg =
  {
    body: "Testing",
    brokerProperties: {
      ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc: scheduled_time
    }
  };
sbService.sendQueueMessage(queueName, msg, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Failed Tx: ', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent ' + msg);
    }
  });
```

However, simply passing the same `msg` object to the output binding the `brokerProperties` seem to be ignored. I HAVE confirmed that the function output binding works in general (properly configured).

```
context.done(null,
  {
    body: "Testing",
    brokerProperties: {
      ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc: scheduled_time
    }
  });
```

Is it possible to leverage output bindings to do this or do I really need to add `azure-sb` and all this code for such a simple parameter? Is there a better way to call an azure function in the future?

The Node SDK docs don't even include `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property so it's been impossible to find any info in the docs.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116319/send-message-from-an-azure-servicebus-topic-after-a-specific-delay-with-node-js/

Comment: @Thomas that refers to the service bus library which I have working. I'm trying to get it working with an output binding.

Comment: Have a look here, it seems that there is an open issue https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/454

Comment: @Thomas that seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm not sure why this didn't come up in any of my searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is does not seems to be supported ATM, see this Github Issue:

- [Enhancement: Add Scheduled Queue Messages to Service Bus Binding Documentation](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/454)